# React testing library wrapper component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

i seem to be stuck with an issue, i have a component which inside has a template wrapper around the jsx, this template wrapper is the header with tabs etc it looks like this:

`const Component =() => { return ( <TemplateWrapper> all the components jsx content </TemplateWrapper> ) }`

when i render the Component all i get is the TemplateWrapper content and none of the page jsx content that i would like to test.
so if anyone can help, how do i render the page content and not just the TemplateWrapper components content?
thanks for any help

I tried to mock the TemplateWrapper, but this didnt seem to work,

`jest.mock(/TemplateWrapper, () => ({TemplateWrapper: jest.fn()}))`

I also tried to use beforeAll to execute the mock wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mock, you're currently replacing the entire `TemplateWrapper` component with a mock function. If you want to keep the children intact, you need to make sure your mock function returns its children.

you could use a mock function like this as an example:

```
jest.mock('./TemplateWrapper', () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        default: jest.fn(({children}) => <div>{children}</div>)
    };
});
```

In the above mock, we're replacing `TemplateWrapper` with a mock function that returns a `div` that contains all its children. Now when you use `TemplateWrapper` in your tests, it should render its children as expected.

Remember to replace `'./TemplateWrapper'` with the actual path to your `TemplateWrapper` component.

Answer (score 0):

your component should render all the DOM related to TemplateWrapper and all its children, this is the expected behavior of RTL, if you didn't find the jsx of the inner component probably it is not rendered yet in the DOM, so you need to wait for the component to completely rendered.

so, if you have a blocking component blocking the inner children to rendered such as a loader. so you need to wait for the loader to be removed from the dom.

```
waitForElementToBeRemoved( //blocking element);
```